# How to dynamically change html elements and copy attributes with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can you change the hyrarchy / structure of html when it's rendered with javascript?
I would like to remove a parent div and copy it's attribute and classname
to it's child element. But I want to do this in the whole page that contains a certain class name.

In code example: I need this code

```
<div class="abc" myid="123" position="2">
<div class="someblock">
    <p>Some paragraph</p>
    <img width="140px; height: 140px; class="myimg" src="url to imgage">
</div>
```

changed to :

```
<div class="someblock" class="abc" myid="123" position="2">
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<img width="140px; height: 140px; class="myimg" src="url to imgage" />
</div>
```

Does anyone know how this can be done with JavaScript, or jQuery? 
Thanks in advance!,

Chris.

Comment: A bunch of `jQuery.attr()` followed by `jQuery.unwrap()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.abc .someblock').contents().unwrap().parent().addClass('someblock');
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/VQRQV/1/

Comment: thank you for your example! but this assumes that the child is of the same tag type. In this case div, but this:
`<div class="abc" myid="123" position="2">
    <span class="someblock">
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
        <img width="140px; height: 140px;" class="myimg" src="http://www.google.nl" />
    </span>
</div>`

Should be alterted in to this:
`<span class="someblock" myid="123" position="2">
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
        <img width="140px; height: 140px;" class="myimg" src="http://www.google.nl" />
    </span>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<script>

    $('.abc').each(function(){
        $(this).children().addClass($(this).attr('class'));
        $(this).children().attr('myid', $(this).attr('myid'));
        $(this).children().attr('position', $(this).attr('position'));
        $('body').append($(this).html());

        $(this).remove();

    });

</script>
```

Be careful.

Comment: You could and should use chaining here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.someblock').each(function () {
    var pt = $(this).parent(),
        cl = pt.attr('class'),
        id = pt.attr('id'),
        pos = pt.attr('position');
    $(this).unwrap().attr({id:id, position:pos}).addClass(cl);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this could help:

```
function deleteParent(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var grandParent = parent.parentNode;
    var html = parent.innerHTML;
    grandParent.removeChild(parent);
    grandParent.innerHTML += html;
}
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I was looking for, but it is very clear to understad how you can remove a parentNode.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById('123');
  if(el) {
    el.className += el.className ? ' someblock' : 'abc';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this first by getting all the elements as
var allElem = document.getElementByID ("*");
then loop through all the elements.

To get to child element check whether a element has children find the last child and a get attribute value example:

var elemVal = allElem[i].className ; or allElem[i].getAttribute("xyx")

and then put the value of this element to desired element in html.

document.getElementById("div").className = elemVal ;